# Adjust function created in R

Tags: r

Could you help me to write the function correctly. First, I'll show you an example:

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    X1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    X2 = c("4","3","1","2"),
    X3 = c("1", "2","3","2"),
    X4 = c("1", "2","3","2"),
    XM1 = c(200, 300, 200, 200),
    XMR0 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    XMR01 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    XMR02 = c(300,300,300,300),
    XMR03 = c(300,300,300,300),
    XMR04 = c(300,250,350,350)),row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


f1 <- function(data){ 
  
  data %>% 
    transmute(across(matches("^X\\d+$")),
              XM1, across(starts_with("XMR"), ~ XM1 - .x, 
                          .names = "{.col}_PV" )) 
}

f1(df1)

> f1(df1)
  X1 X2 X3 X4 XM1 XMR0_PV XMR01_PV XMR02_PV XMR03_PV XMR04_PV
1  1  4  1  1 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -100
2  1  3  2  2 300       0        0        0        0       50
3  1  1  3  3 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
4  1  2  2  2 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
```

Now I have a similar database, but the column names are different.

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    date1 = c("2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06"),
    date2 = c("2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-09","2022-01-10"),
    Week = c("Sunday","Monday","Sunday","Monday"),
    Category = c("EFG", "ABC","EFG","ABC"),
    DR1 = c(200, 300, 200, 200),
    DRM0 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM01 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM02 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM03 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM04 = c(300,250,350,350)),row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I would like to create a function that can be called `f2`. What would my function look like now, compared to `f1` above?

**Output expected**

```
  Id      date2   Week Category DR1 DRM0_PV DRM01_PV DRM02_PV DRM03_PV DRM04_PV
1  1 2022-01-02 Sunday      EFG 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -100
2  1 2022-01-03 Monday      ABC 300       0        0        0        0       50
3  1 2022-01-09 Sunday      EFG 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
4  1 2022-01-10 Monday      ABC 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
```

Comment: It's the same calculation procedure, the difference is that the names of some columns have been changed. I have entered the expected output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may add some additional arguments in the function as input

1. `colnm` - column name that is used to subtract as string (`ensym` converts to symbol and it is evaluated with `!!` - by using `ensym`, we can also use unquoted argument as input)
2. `pat` - prefix pattern of the column name to be used for looping `across` those columns
3. `cols_del` - columns to be deleted.  By default it is `NULL`.  Thus, if we don't have the fourth argument, none of the columns are deleted.

```
f1 <- function(data, colnm, pat, cols_del = NULL){
 
  colnm <- rlang::ensym(colnm)
  data %>% 
     mutate(!! colnm, across(starts_with(pat), ~  !! colnm - .x, 
        .names = "{.col}_PV" ), .keep = "unused")  %>%
     select(-any_of(cols_del))
  }
```

---

The code loops `across` those columns that have prefix 'DRM/XMR' and subtract the value of column input in `colnm`, and return only those columns `unused` i.e. as we are creating new columns with `.names`, the looped columns are not returned in the data, but we need 'DR1' or 'XM1', thus it is selected (`!! colnm`), and in the last step remove `any_of` 'cols_del'ed from the output

---

-testing

```
> f1(df1, "DR1", "DRM", "date1")
  Id      date2   Week Category DR1 DRM0_PV DRM01_PV DRM02_PV DRM03_PV DRM04_PV
1  1 2022-01-02 Sunday      EFG 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -100
2  1 2022-01-03 Monday      ABC 300       0        0        0        0       50
3  1 2022-01-09 Sunday      EFG 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
4  1 2022-01-10 Monday      ABC 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
```

-using the original 'df1'

```
> f1(df1, "XM1", "XMR")
  X1 X2 X3 X4 XM1 XMR0_PV XMR01_PV XMR02_PV XMR03_PV XMR04_PV
1  1  4  1  1 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -100
2  1  3  2  2 300       0        0        0        0       50
3  1  1  3  3 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
4  1  2  2  2 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
```